# how to swap the first number and last number in a line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I want to swap first number and last number ,but while doing so am not getting proper output

```
echo 1234jj h777 jj89 | sed 's/^\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\(.*\)\([0-9]*\{1,\}\)$/\3\2\1/'
```

I'm getting output as:

```
9jj h777 jj81234
```

Expected output:

```
89jj h777 jj81234
```

why it is not considering 89 as number (it is taking only 9)?

Comment: Why is your desired result (`89jj h777 jj81234`) one character longer than your input (`1234jj h777 jj89`)?

Comment: i guess your expected output is `89jj h777 jj1234` (the 8 not to be repeated.)  We need more explanations. Are your 'numbers' always separated by space? Do you need to reverse the numbers and letters? jj89 vs 89jj?

Comment: It does consider `8` to be a number. However, `.*` is greedy and matches everything up to the last digit. You should also specify what should happen for input like this: `12345`.

Comment: Please specify the output if the input ends in a letter.  Example, suppose the input is `1a 2a`.  Should the output be `a 2a1` or `1a 2a`?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]+)(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)$/\3\2\1/' file
```

Or in longhand:

```
sed 's/^\([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*\)\(.*[^[:digit:]]\)\([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*\)$/\3\2\1/' file
```

The trick is to use greed `.*` to swallow up the digits of a number, which is fine in the first number but excessive in the second. By anchoring the start of the second number by the preceding non-digit, the numbers may be captured and then re-arranged.

Answer (score 0):

Following `sed` may help you in same.

```
echo "1234jj h777 jj89" | sed 's/\([^a-z]*\)\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]*\)/\5\2 \3 \4\1/g'
```

***EDIT:*** Adding non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
echo "1234jj h777 jj89" | sed '
s/\([^a-z]*\) \
\([^ ]*\) \
\([^ ]*\) \
\([^0-9]*\) \
\([0-9]*\) \
/\5\2 \3 \4\1/g'
```

Comment: Fails if input is `1 2` -- it outputs `1 2`, (rather than `2 1`).

Comment: @agc, Thank you agc but I had provided solution as per OP's ask, please do let me know if I missed something here. Will delete my answer then.

Comment: Please don't delete it, the Q isn't so clear as we're absolutely sure what the OP wants.  See [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136797/how-to-swap-the-first-number-and-last-number-in-a-line/48138821#comment83255366_48136797).

Answer (score 0):

*POSIX* shell:

```
echo 1234jj h777 jj89 | 
{ read x ; h=${x##*[^0-9]} t=${x%%[^0-9]*} x="${x#$t}" x="${x%$h}" ;
  echo "$h$x${x:+$t}";}
```

Output:

```
89jj h777 jj1234
```

---

Note: for a large input file this would be slower than `sed`.  For just a line or two it's faster, because there's no need to load `sed`.